# Description of various placements of PPs in a syntax tree

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, pragmatics, prepositions, verb-phrase

How would you describe the difference in modifications a PP can make to a VP i.e.

[I want to visit them][before this time]

versus

[I want to [visit them before this time]]

I understand there is very little difference in this context and I'm struggling to see how you would justify placing the PP in one place of a syntax tree versus another

Comment: Your second example is essentially correct, though the marker "to" belongs with the subordinate clause: "I want [to visit them before this time]". "Want" is a catenative verb and the subordinate infinitival clause "to visit them before this time" is its catenative complement. The PP "before this time" is a temporal adjunct within the subordinate clause.

Comment: "before this time" could modify either the VP "visit them" or the VP "want to visit them", and there are two corresponding interpretations (though the first interpretation describes an odd situtation in which your wants come and go).  English ambiguities of this sort are commonplace.

Comment: In case you're interested, I've put up a tree diagram which shows that the PP "before this time" is a modifier in the structure of the subordinate clause.

Comment: @Greg Lee - I think you meant modifying "want to ..." is the odd one.  That interpretation could be forced (weakly) with a comma after 'them', or (strongly) by fronting the adverbial phrase.

Comment: @amI, yes, you're right that I meant to refer to the second interpretation, not the first.  However, fronting the "before" phrase does not eliminate the ambiguity, for me.

Comment: If the main verb was 'wanted' instead of 'want', I think the ambiguity would be resolved by fronting. What if fronted 'before this time' was 'before tomorrow'?  Without some clue to absolute time it does remain ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the adjunct "before this time" belongs not in the matrix clause, but in the catenative complement clause, as shown in this tree:

[image]

Comment: In addition, "visit them" is a VP (it could be replaced by "do so"), and "to visit them before this time" is a NP (it could be replaced by "it/that/this").

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say, Greg. While it's true that the _to_ that marks infinitivals derives historically from the preposition _to_ (notice the similarity between _I went **to** the doctor_ and _I went **to** see the doctor_) it long ago lost its prepositional properties. It is unique since no other item has exactly the same grammatical properties. It's very widely accepted as a member of the subordinator category, a special marker for VP's of infinitival clauses.

Comment: What does the category of "to" have to do with my comment? I don't see any relationship.  Maybe I should construct examples for you to illustrate the evidence I gave.  (1) "I will visit them, and I want to do so before Wednesday." [do so = visit them] (2) "Shirley wants me to visit them before Wednesday, and I want that, too." [that = to visit them before Wednesday]

Comment: @GregLee Because I recall you saying that it's a preposition. There is no satisfactory evidence to support your view that infinitival clauses are actually NPs. It's an absurd assertion, and one that is not held by any grammarian I know.

Comment: I'm sure I never said that "to" of the infinitive was a preposition. But I still don't see the relevance.  Treating some for-to complements as NPs has been standard in classical transformational grammar since at least Peter Rosenbaum's MIT dissertation "The Grammar of English Predicate Complement Constructions".  But you didn't need to know that, since I  gave you the evidence above.  Please -- more evidence and less rhetoric.

Comment: @GregLee I seem to recall over on ELU you saying that infinitivals were in fact PP's.  Unfortunately the OP got p****d off and deleted their question, so we can't reference it. So, first you say they are PPs and then you claim they are NPs. What next, AdjPs or AdvPs? The simple fact is that "to visit them before this time" is an infinitival VP introduced by the subordinator "to". The VP heads an infinitival clause, not an NP.

Comment: No.  You're recalling my discussion of a construction which I claimed had both a preposition "for" and a "for" from the "for-to" complementizer (though not both could be explicit).

Comment: And the NP I'm talking about here is not part of the complement of "want", but rather is the direct object of "want".

Answer (score 0):

Compare it to this:

```
[I want [them to visit me [before this time]]]
[I want [them to visit me] [before this time]]
```

I drew you the trees of your two and these two examples:

Your examples:

[image]
[image: edit: (PRO) or PRO is a typo; both are the "semantically controlled" but phonologically null pronoun PRO (ntbc with pro with is slightly different)]

edit: (PRO) in the above tree and PRO in this one should both be the same (typo). PRO is the "semantically controlled" but phonologically null pronoun. Here it refers to "I", that is, its (accusative) form "me" (as in "I want me/myself to ...")

Compare your examples to this:

[image]
[image]

Try the last ones with "wanted" or "will want" instead. The meaning is different.